# Matching two head models by sculpting

Tags: sculpting

Firstly, I am just a beginner, so I might not understand what you are saying. Sorry in advance. I have two human head models in Blender. One of them is taken from a game as a template, and the other one is what I am trying to implement into the game. Because of the game's limitations, I cannot directly implement my model. So, I have attempted to sculpt the template head to match mine. However, it is proving to be quite difficult for me. Is there any way to automatically sculpt the template to match my model?

Comment: Simple answer: No, but since you haven't provided any images of what you have and what you're trying to achieve it's almost impossible to give any advice. See [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).